# Need help understanding this python error return (Google search doesn't help)

Tags: python

In python code. When you see a negative in front of a Error Flag, what does it mean?

return -errno.EACCES

Comment: What does a minus in front of any other expression (take `1` as a super-simple example) mean?

Comment: Even Google search did not explain what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a C style error return. A practice that is popular is to return a meaningful non-negative result of the function on success or a negative error code on failure.

In this case, the error EACCES means that [permision was denied](http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html).

(See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848729/c-why-return-a-negative-errno-e-g-return-eio))

Comment: Never heard of this practice (I don't says that it doesn't exist). The common practice is to return something different than 0. glibc functions return positive values on error.

Comment: @Ugo, this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848729/c-why-return-a-negative-errno-e-g-return-eio) gives some good info on why you'd choose a negative return value. I should probably have incorporated that kind of information into my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The author may has restricted error code to negative value in order to be able to return various (positive) success values.

The convention seems to be used by some people:
http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=%22return+-errno%22+lang%3Apython&sbtn=Search

Answer (score 1):

It means negation.  `errno.EACCES` (permission denied) is the number 13 (positive).  The author of that code had a convention where he wanted the error number to be negative to be interpreted by their code later.

Presumably, he has a reason for adopting this convention.  E.g., the function returns non-negative integers on non-errors that are used later on in the program.